# iOS 7.1: Border around search bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, ios7.1

Before updating the SDK to 7.1, my search bar looked like this:

[image]

I was using this code to achieve this affect:

```
searchBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor turquoiseColor];
[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

After updating to 7.1, now it looks like this:

[image]

If I change the second line of the above code to this:

```
[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor turquoiseColor]];
```

Then I get this:

[image]

Which has a weird black border on the top and bottom. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, for some reason this doesn't happen if you use an image, so what i did is just use a image with the color that i needed

```
[_searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backroundOfSearchBar"]]
```